# Aggregate with in-class initialization - as default argument

Tags: c++, aggregate, language-lawyer, c++17, default-parameters

The following code does not compile (GCC, clang):

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        int i = 1;
        int j = 2;
    };
    void foo (const 
        inner& param = 
        inner{}) const {}
};

int main() {
    outer{}.foo();
}
```

However, adding a default constructor (with implementation) to `inner` solves the issue. Moving out `inner` to the namespace scope also helps.

What's the problem here? I'd appreciate references to the standard.

Comment: Are you sure that you build in C++17 mode? In C++11 structures with inline member initializations were *not* aggregates. This was removed in C++14. See e.g. [this aggregate iniitalization reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for details. Or perhaps it's a bug in the compilers? Have you tried with e.g. MSVC++ (the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is good for this)?

Comment: And *what* error are you getting? Please include the exact, complete and full error output in the question.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I believe sscce is enough ;).  And thanks for the pointer to the duplicate, couldn't find it

Comment: @IgorR. It's me who flagged duplicate.